# How to create a callback in Java

Tags: java, callback

I am a newbie to Java.I am trying to learn callback in Java.I found a lot of results by googling.But i need some simple example that can explain the use of callback implementation in Java.I wish it should be something like a timer that print some message after every one minute.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html. You pass an object of a given class, and the method receiving the object calls one of the methods of the object.

Comment: show us what you googled?

Comment: Take a look at [`Runnable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) or [`Callable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html).

Comment: ... and [Future](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html).

Comment: See the [Executors tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html) and [ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) in particular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I am printing** current Date and Time for you **using java.util.Date** :

```
import java.util.Date;               //importing this package just to use Date()

public class StackOverflowQ {

 public interface CallBackInt{
    String doJob(String str);
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {

    CallBackInt variable = new CallBackInt(){       //using the interface
        public String doJob(String str) {       //doJob method from interface
            return (str + new Date().toString()); 
                  //used .toString() as return type of doJob is String
        }
    };


    while (true) {                            //infinite loop

        System.out.println(variable.doJob("Current Date Instance is: "));
        try {
            Thread.sleep(60*1000);            
            //time is in miliseconds and 60*1000 mili sec=60 seconds = 1 minute
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {   
         //if there are any Exception thrown, this will catch it and help you !

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
}
```

And, **thread** is a thread of execution in any program.
Any process that is currently in execution can be treated as a thread. **So, here in this program** **Thread.sleep** refers to the current thread (which is main() method currently). So it pauses the main() thread for 60 seconds and resumes it after the pause and then again prints the current Date.

Comment: This isn't exactly what I would call a _callback_...

Comment: Ok then I will edit my answer for this.

Comment: I would upvote this answer if it respected the Java naming conventions. Classes always start with an uppercase letter, and they never contain an underscore. Ignoring an InterruptedException is also a bad idea.

Comment: Yeah..Thanks. Your suggestions will improve my way of programming

Answer (score 0):

Being object-oriented, Java does not have [callbacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_programming%29) in the old-fashioned sense. Instead, we do something along the lines of the [Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern), passing an instance of an interface that requires one or more methods named a certain way to be invoked by the other object. Passing a lambda in Java 8 or later would be another approach.

See the [Executors tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html) and [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) class in particular.

Here is example code taken straight from that class’ documentation.

```
 import static java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.*;
 class BeeperControl {
   private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

   public void beepForAnHour() {
     final Runnable beeper = new Runnable() {
       public void run() { System.out.println("beep"); }
     };
     final ScheduledFuture<?> beeperHandle = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(beeper, 10, 10, SECONDS);
     scheduler.schedule(new Runnable() {
       public void run() { beeperHandle.cancel(true); }
     }, 60 * 60, SECONDS);
   }
 }
```